# Is there any way I can use more than two USB storage devices at once with my 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I have seen many posts about using a USB hub to plug in multiple drives, but apparently it doesn't work for me. I have 3 16GB drives, 1 4GB, and 1 2GB drive, but no matter the combination, I can only get two to work at once. Is there any way I can use three or more at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

It's limited to 2 devices only.

> You can have 2 devices connected to the console at a time, enabling up to 32GB of simultaneous storage.

Source: http://majornelson.com/2010/03/26/USB-Memory-Support-for-the-Xbox-360-coming-April-6th/